# Ubuntu boot slowed down after installing Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

After installing Windows 10 on a completely different SSD the Ubuntu boot time went up from a couple of seconds to a whole minute. What could be causing this problem and is there any fix?

I use the following partition scheme:

```
sda           8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 232,9G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   243M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   7,5G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 232,9G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 690,9G  0 part
```

Where sda is a Samsung 850 Evo SSD and nvme0n1 is Samsung 970 Evo Plus SSD.

Ubuntu version is 20.04.4

blkid output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="52fffe85-16d3-4ce4-811c-44a89f063536" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d327ae3e-6648-4615-b48f-ed2b1ee839e1"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="86f19b7d-5428-4075-9c88-5a9330625240" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1d902ba3-b632-484d-bb9b-7c152902981d"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="5B02-C89B" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="095122c8-d3da-4a38-9157-44e1a7c0f9c4"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="6A1EA75B58D0B2E9" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="Media" PARTUUID="ee7d88a6-37ec-4462-9817-cafd8281e66c"
/dev/sda1: UUID="48D8D885D8D87324" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="53857cd5-72c3-4f19-a0c8-e3f3f3b10402"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="94abc63c-2932-4f39-9b14-77d9fb338e76"
```

While inspecting the startup log I found these lines:

```
apr 02 00:17:16 systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
apr 02 00:17:46 systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
apr 02 00:18:39 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-05ce9340\x2db920\x2d4ede\x2da6c6\x2d060bfcb38489.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-05ce9340\x2db920\x2d4ede\x2da6c6\x2d060bfcb38489.device/start timed>
apr 02 00:18:39 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/05ce9340-b920-4ede-a6c6-060bfcb38489.
apr 02 00:18:39 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/05ce9340-b920-4ede-a6c6-060bfcb38489.
apr 02 00:18:39 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
```

Running `cat /etc/fstab` gives me:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=86f19b7d-5428-4075-9c88-5a9330625240 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=5B02-C89B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=52fffe85-16d3-4ce4-811c-44a89f063536 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=05ce9340-b920-4ede-a6c6-060bfcb38489 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

So, as far as I understand this problem is caused by the swap partition of an old Ubuntu that was installed on sda before I installed Windows on it.

Comment: When does the delay occur? Is it to get to the Grub menu, or from there to the Ubuntu login screen, or from when you type your password to when you have a functional system? Add details of your Ubuntu version and hardware (including disks / partitions) and someone will try to help. Thanks.

Comment: @Will it's after I pick ubuntu from the grub menu

Comment: Please type `sudo blkid | grep -E 'sda|nvme'` into a terminal and append the output to your original post.

Comment: You can look at the startup log entries (and their timestamps) by the terminal command `sudo journalctl -b 0`. If you haven't disabled Windows' "Fast Boot" option, I recommend doing so. Windows' "Fast Boot" option leaves NTFS disks in a weird state that Linux doesn't understand.

Comment: @waltinator, thanks, I found the entries that cause the delay, but I don't really know what they mean tho

Comment: Make a backup of your `/etc/fstab` file via `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak` and edit your original `/etc/fstab` file and comment out the last line `UUID=05ce9340-b920-4ede-a6c6-060bfcb38489...` by typing a `#` in front of the line, like `#UUID=05ce9340-b920-4ede-a6c6-060bfcb38489...` and reboot after saving. This should fix the problem.

Comment: @paladin thanks, that solved the problem

Comment: your fstab contained two different swap partitions. You may have only one. Good catch from @paladin!